# Precise Measurement of Noisy Voltage

Tags: adc, measurement, automotive

I'm working on a circuit that will have a current shunt before a device connected to a truck's 12V system. This system can have voltage drift, and large transients during operation. The connected device has several switching regulators on-board, and the current shunt needs to be connected in front of the device. I'd like to have a digital representation of the voltage at either end of the current shunt. I really don't need fast sampling, even 10Hz would do. Preferably the output would be in I2C or SPI.

Would an ADC be the correct device to use in this scenario? How would I protect it from the voltage spikes and drift?

Additionally, what are some components that I could place before the device in order to suppress the voltage spikes and other noise, to assist the regulators?

Comment: Why a shunt rather than a hall effect transducer? Is the shunt to be on the high side or on the the low side?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Mainly because I thought it would be easier to use a current shunt. The device may draw an absolute maximum of 5A, but typically only 1A or 2A. I want to be able to sense changes in current of ~20mA (or less). Would a hall effect sensor work well in this application?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany For the second question: If you are asking whether the shunt will be on +12V or GND, then I don't think it matters in this case. Would putting it on the GND line mitigate the transient and drift issues?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'change'. 20mA in 5A is 0.4%, pretty tight if that's a system accuracy spec. A closed-loop Hall transducer would probably be okay.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I mean I want to be able to measure in at least 20mA increments. What makes using a hall effect sensor better than the current shunt?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a low-side shunt and have +/- supplies available, an instrumentation amplifier followed by an ADC would do the trick. You will need to filter the input so that the transients don't get through, or make ADC measurements fast enough (and without the input saturating) that you don't get significant aliasing and can filter the ADC outputs digitally.

Alternatively, you could use a closed-loop Hall current transducer such as the LEM [LTSR](http://www.lem.com/docs/products/ltsr%206-np.pdf) series. The lowest current they have is 6A, then 15A, but you could put multiple turns through the primary to get integer fractions of those full scale values (for example, four turns through the 15A gives you 3.75A full scale).

[image]

They can be powered from your 5V supply and perhaps connected directly to a microcontroller ADC through a filter (application notes love to use Sallen-Key filters for this).

A Hall sensor is superior for this kind of application because it provides galvanic isolation, so common mode noise won't easily find its way to your circuit. Closed-loop Hall transducers null out the field from input current by an auxiliary coil so they have good linearity.

The shunt circuit might be cheaper, but requires more care to ensure the common mode input range of the instrumentation amplifier is not exceeded (it might be a lot less than the supply rails) and the voltage across the shunt terminals will necessarily be rather low. If you allow 50 or 100mV across the shunt at 5A, then your 20mA is only 200uV or 400uV.

If you're just building one, I'd suggest the Hall sensor to save you time. If you're making a product that will be produced in quantity the shunt might look attractive.

Comment: The current shunt I was looking at using would be 0.05Ω, causing 20mA to create 1mV. I was planning to create one, _maybe_ 10 of these. I don't have a -5V rail, so I'll look into the Hall effect method. Thanks!

Comment: The Hall effect sensor you mentioned costs $25.20 on Digikey at single quantities. Using Digikey, I wasn't able to find any under $10 that meet your suggestions.

Comment: You're right, it isn't cheap. You can generate the -5V rail or an isolated +/-5V power supply. You can use a instrumentation amplifier or float the ADC on your ADC output, and use isolated digital signals. All this stuff is complex, with things to go wrong, and does cost money. You could use a handheld DVM with an isolated RS-232 output and avoid the analog regime entirely (probably more like $100). Lots of ways to skin the cat, but not much that is simple + cheap + trouble-free.

Comment: If I place the shunt on the GND line from the device, could I place and ADC directly on the two terminals?

Comment: Also, do you have an answer to the second part of my question, regarding noise reduction? Would a large-value capacitor with a high voltage rating do the job there?

Comment: @CaiB Well, no, you really want a filter like the Sallen-Key I suggested or perhaps just an RC filter, but the requirements will suggest the topology. If you're happy enough with 1Hz BW then a single pole passive RC might work, but there's really not enough information to work on, and designing a data acquisition system goes beyond the scope of what can be answered in this kind of forum. There are some ADCs with built in programmable gain amplifiers that could accept a shunt input more-or-less directly if you get the common-mode range right (meaning a negative supply, most likely).